# Customizing ebay store HTML and CSS code (How to?)

Tags: html, css, ebay-design-templates

I have an ebay store and it has some themes but I would like to be able to change the CSS and HTML code myself.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it several times earlier. Main thing is to add link to stylesheet (which is on your server). If i remember correct, you can add it where HTML for header is added, and then style elements generated by eBay. (Don't use id)

Comment: I've done that it's I can change some things but there seems to be a lot of inline style in the store code and no class or id names on it. How to I change that?

Comment: use elements that have classes and then by tree set styles for example: .classname > div:first-child > div + div { .... }

Comment: The problem is that this wouldn't overwrite inline styles and the ebay code has tables with inline styles and no classes or id's on it. Is there any way on accessing the actual template html of the ebay store please?